# Can I use Apache Avro just for JSON documents schema validation?

Tags: java, schema, avro

I know that Avro is very fast data serialisation and deserialisation system. It also provides rich data structure for schema defination. Is it possible to use Avro just for JSON documents schema validation? For example, I have thousands of JSON documents and I want to validate those JSON documents against a predefined Avro schema pretty fast. Can Avro be the good choise here?

Note: I want to do this in a java application.